# how to keep track of time after object is created in java

Tags: java

I am not sure how to build this setup in Java

Once I make an object, I want object to be destroyed after certain amount of time. Also i want to destroy the object when i trigger it. So the object will be destroyed after set time for sure but it can also be destroyed by the trigger. However, I also want my object to be interactive with other function until it is destroyed.

Can you help me what function to use and how to build it.

Comment: sounds like you want your program to crash

Comment: Can you actually tell us what you need? Some sort of caching mechanism? What is wrong with the existing garbage collection?

Comment: you can see this answer which is already asked http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/201102/keeping-track-of-all-objects-of-a-class

Comment: Could you please be more specific? At a minimum, you should try to get started yourself, and, if you get stuck, come back with a specific question and a relevant sample of your code. I encourage you to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for guidance on asking good questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

long timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
if that is what you need